# Why can't I run migrations on my test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I'm trying to run my RoR app in test environment, but I have a problem with migrations on my test database.

My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: questionnaires-development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: questionnaires-test
```

Now I create my databases with that commands:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb -O karol questionnaires-development
sudo -u postgres createdb -O karol questionnaires-test
```

Next I run a migration for the development database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

I can easily see it works:

```
== 20180719143415 CreateQuestions: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:questions)
   -> 0.0894s
== 20180719143415 CreateQuestions: migrated (0.0896s) =========================

== 20180722122658 CreateQuestionnaires: migrating =============================
-- create_table(:questionnaires)
   -> 0.1050s
== 20180722122658 CreateQuestionnaires: migrated (0.1051s) ====================

Database migrated.
```

I can also list my tables with Postgres CLI, everything nice:

```
questionnaires-development=# \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------------------+-------+-------
 public | ar_internal_metadata | table | karol
 public | questionnaires       | table | karol
 public | questions            | table | karol
 public | schema_migrations    | table | karol
(4 rows)
```

But now I'd like to do the same with my `questionnaires-test` database. So I run that command:

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

But results are worrisome:

```
Database migrated.
```

Trying to list my tables my worries get confirmed:

```
questionnaires-test=# \dt
No relations found.
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: I got that: "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:test:prepare' (see --tasks)"

Comment: But I found very tricky and ugly way to solve my problem - I can just temporarily change my development database to `development-test` and run migrations for that as it was development one.

Comment: Although I still want to meet clear and working solution.

Comment: Can you try to run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` (rake instead of rails). I don't know why but I had some issues with the `rails`command and the inline env var.

Comment: @Oxynum - no, still doesn't work for me